# Closing opened database connections?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have two datasources in my web application. i am getting connection as `dataSource1.getConnection();`.

my question is consider below code:

```
Connection connection = null;
connection = dataSource1.getConnection();
connection = dataSource2.getConnection();
connection.close();
```

I am getting `dataSource1` connection and immediately assigning `dataSource2` connection to connection variable.

As I am closing `dataSource2` connection, does `dataSource1` connection remains open?  Or do I need to do as below?

```
Connection connection = null;
connection = dataSource1.getConnection();
connection.close();
connection = dataSource2.getConnection();
connection.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example is right, the first one will leave an open connection. Also, you should always close resources (connections, in this case) inside a `finally` block, for example:

```
Connection connection = null;

try {
    connection = dataSource1.getConnection();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle exception
} finally {
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // handle exception
    }   
}

try {
    connection = dataSource2.getConnection();
    connection.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle exception
} finally {
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do as you show in your second code example.

In the first case, the Garbage Collector **may** clean up the mess for you (after an undefined amount of time) and close the connection that you've lost reference to (provided the JDBC driver vendor implemented the appropriate logic in the `finalize` method of their `Connection` implementation), however it is considered extremely **bad practice** to rely on this to happen.

Comment: Why would the GC `close` the connection during garbage collection?

Comment: ~user384706 the GC would close the connection if the implementor of the JDBC driver called close in the finalize method.

Comment: @user384706 Updated answer to be more clear about this, as noted by MarlinPierce.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) class implements the [`AutoClosable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface, which defines "a resource that must be closed when it is no longer needed". So connection objects are defined as needing a call to their `close()` method in order to be properly managed.

On the other hand, the `Connection.close()` method is documented as "releasing the Connection object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for them to be automatically released". Which implies that somewhere the connection resources will be freed eventually automatically.

On balance, though, I'd say that it's better to explicitly close any connections you no longer need.

Comment: In general JDBC connections are not automatically closed, except by garbage collection **if** the driver implementer did his job.